# calculating pi with decimal on python with machin formula

Tags: python, decimal, pi

I am trying to calculate pi with the Machin formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula.
It works when I do not use python's decimal library to get arbitrary precision (source code: http://pastie.org/9650936) but it only gave like 14 digits (3.14159265358979400417638316866941750049591064453125). I decided I wanted to get arbitrary precision but when I did the code for that, it changed the final value for pi. All I really changed was adding Decimal() for all the values, so I'm wondering what is wrong. Source code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 100
pi = Decimal(0)
ctwo = Decimal(239)
cfive = Decimal(5)
inc = Decimal(3)
a = Decimal(1)
epi = Decimal(1)/Decimal(5)
opi = Decimal(1)/Decimal(239)
for a in range(1, 10):
 if (a%2 != 0):
  epi -= Decimal(1)/Decimal((Decimal(inc)*(Decimal(cfive)**Decimal(inc))))
  opi -= Decimal(1)/Decimal((inc*(ctwo**inc)))
  inc = inc + Decimal(2)
  a = a + Decimal(1)
 elif (a%2 == 0):
  epi += Decimal(1)/Decimal((inc*(cfive**inc)))
  opi += Decimal(1)/Decimal((inc*(ctwo**inc)))
  inc = inc + Decimal(2)
  a = a + Decimal(1)
pi = Decimal(4)*Decimal((epi)-(opi))
pi = Decimal(4) * pi
print pi
```

and the value I get is slightly off, (3.091383741564895010542821040108680015248075199241027019420298084548814621985888671367248358277198010)
and I have done some experimenting and haven't been able to find out why it's doing this or how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `Decimal`, that is meant to see the exact value that is being stored in the machine. Due to floating point problems. for instance, Deciaml(1/3.0) = `0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125`, that's not `1/3`. You and I both know that, however the computer does not, so Python and all languages round that off

Comment: @ZWiki: with `.prec=100`: `Decimal(1)/Decimal(3)` == `Decimal('0.333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333')`